# Google chrome store limits buyers regions

Tags: google-chrome-app, android-pay, chrome-web-store

According to [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/pricing) I should be able to sell to worldwide with the chrome store BUT when I choose one-time payment with Chrome Web Store Payments allot of regions suddenly disappeared!!

For example I don't see Russia and Ukraine after I change pricing from FREE to one-time payment.

How to enable payments from ALL regions for my app?

Comment: The documentation you quote precisely lists the regions you can sell to. Russia is not mentioned anywhere, Ukraine is mentioned in a weird additional list.

Comment: @Xan, read more careful: Buyers in unsupported regions might be able to purchase apps, but they can't pay in their local currency and might have to pay international transaction fees. And according to the document Ukraine is in the list of supported regions.

Comment: Which probably means you won't see them as regions in the app's dashboard entry, but does not automatically mean they cannot see your app.

Comment: @Xan, I have friends in russia and ukraine and they are not able to buy my app. they can see app in a listings though.

Comment: I would suggest asking this question in the relevant [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-apps), you may get more direct attention here. But I wouldn't get my hopes up.